# Toggle Background Image - The image did not appear

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this code below. When I click on the link, if it has the class 'home-link', I would like to show the background-image. If it doesn't have the class, no image will be shown.

**The problem is:**
Initially the image appears because the css file is bringing its 
and disappear after the clicking on the link that doesn't have the class and I can´t bring the image back by clicking on the link that contains the class.
It is working perfectly with 'background-color' but not with 'background-image'. How can I solve it?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Redirect, NavLink } from 'react- 
router-dom'

import Home from './Home';
import NotaBiografica from './Biografy';
import Portfolio from './Portfolio';

class MainMenu extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
   super(props)
   this.handleOnClick = this.handleOnClick.bind(this)
}
 handleOnClick(e) {

 if (e.target.classList.contains('home-link')) {
   e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundImage = 
  'url("images/col3_esq.gif")'  
   e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = 'black'
 } else {
    e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundImage = 'none'
    e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = 'green'
 }
}

render() {

return (
  <div>
    <Router>
      <div className="wrapper2">
        <nav className="menu-principal">
          <ul>
            <li><NavLink onClick={this.handleOnClick} className="home-link" activeClassName="active" exact to="/">home</NavLink></li>
            <li><NavLink onClick={this.handleOnClick} activeClassName="active" exact to="/biografy">biografy</NavLink></li>
            <li><NavLink onClick={this.handleOnClick} activeClassName="active" exact to="/portfolio">portfolio</NavLink></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>           
      </div>
    </Router>
   </div>
  )
 }
}

export default MainMenu
```

Comment: any error you are getting ?

Comment: No there aren't any error message.

Comment: your image url is correct ?

Comment: yes it is correct

Comment: Actually, i don't want why it is not working but in my opinion `e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundColor` is very bad usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked on the React dev tool and I figured out that React changes the image URL automatically:

```
'url("images/col3_esq.gif")';
```

to:

```
'url(/static/media/col3_esq.2c4ef96b.gif)'
```

The solution is simply to copy this URL from the react-dev tool and paste it into your script.

Example:

```
e.target.parentNode
      .parentNode
      .parentNode
      .style
      .backgroundImage = 'url("/static/media/col3_esq.2c4ef96b.gif")'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create two css class, one is for backgroundColor and another for backgroundImage.

```
.backgroundColor = {
  background-color: "green"
}

.backgroundImage = {
  background-image: "image path"
}
```

You need to use in your render part accordinglly

```
className={`home-link ${this.props.isActive? 'backgroundImage' : 'backgroundColor'}`}
```